# MVC 4 - Razor - ListBoxFor Error: CS1501: No overload for method 'ListBoxFor' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, listbox

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ProductVersions, new SelectList(Model.ProductVersions, "Id", "Title"), new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

I keep getting the following error:

**CS1501: No overload for method 'ListBoxFor' takes 0 arguments**

When I do the following it works fine:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProductVersions, new SelectList(Model.ProductVersions, "Id", "Title"), "-- Select Version --", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:300px;" })
```

I am new to MVC 4 and razor so I am not entirely sure why this isn't working for a listbox but works for a dropdown. I am trying to use [Bootstrap Dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both should work, your code is fine

Comment: Any idea what could be causing the error mentioned? I'll try clearing my cache.

Comment: error may be in some other view

Comment: I cleared my cache and resolved the issue. Thank you guys!